# SQL export (with joins) change rows to columns - get specific row data for columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working with the volusion cart software so I only have export access. I have the following tables (with a bit of sample data):

```
orders
orderid, shippingmethodid, orderstatus
12345, 218, Ready to Ship
12346, 152, Ready to Ship
12347, 602, Ready to Ship
12348, 10151, Processing


orderdetails
orderid, productcode, productname, qtyonpackingslip, qty
12345, proda-12, product a twelve, 1, 1
12346, prodb-14, product b fourteen, , 1
12346, prodc_15, product c fifteen, 0, 1
12347, prodd-21, product d twenty one, , 1
12347, prode-17, product e seventeen, , 1
12348, prodf-19, product f nineteen, , 1
```

I need to create an export query that will list the product codes as columns rather than rows. meaning that if there are multiple product codes on an order, there should be 1 row for that orderid, & however many columns as there are products in that order but only if the qtyonpackingslip is > 0 or null AND the quantity is > 0. Example of how the result needs to look:

[image]

There should be 10 item columns. I'm hesitant to post what I've tried, partially from embarrassment & partially because it's so wrong I may cause confusion about what I'm trying to do, but here's a few just so you all know I'm REALLY trying:

```
SELECT
o.orderid
, (SELECT productcode, row_number() over (order by productcode) as item1pc
        FROM orderdetails od WHERE item1pcv= 1) As Item1code
, (SELECT productname, row_number() over (order by productname) as item1name
        FROM orderdetails od WHERE item1name = 1) As Item1name
, (SELECT qtyonpackingslip row_number() over (order by qtyonpackingslip) as item1qty
        FROM orderdetails od WHERE item1qty= 1) As Item1qty
, shippingmethodid

 FROM orders o
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT productcode, productname, qtyonpackingslip
    FROM orderdetails od
    LEFT JOIN orders on o.orderid = od.orderid 
    WHERE od.qtyonpackingslip > 0)

 WHERE o.orderstatus = 'Ready to Ship'
```

Not even close, Also tried this:

```
SELECT
o.orderid
, pd1.productcode As item1
, pd1.productname As item1name
, pd1.quantity As item1qty
, o.shippingmethodid

FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT orderid, productcode, productname, qtyonpackingslip, quantity FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderid) AS Row
    , orderid
    , productcode
    , productname
    , quantity
    FROM orderdetails WHERE qtyonpackingslip > 0 
    OR (qtyonpackingslip IS NULL AND quantity > 0) 
    ) As pd1
    ON o.orderid = pd1.orderid AND Row = 1
    WHERE o.orderstatus = 'Ready to Ship'
```

Again, no dice. I've never had to get specific rows before, so I don't know what I'm doing! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I do not know except it's not oracle, its through a cms with user input that exports to csv. I *think* it's sql-server but I wasn't sure enough to tag it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nope :(  I included that I'm using volusion, was hoping someone knew?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name volusion says its sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed, what you really want is not to PIVOT the data. Pivoting turns values from cells in your dataset to columns, and in your case, you still want those values as values. The difference is that you want values that are associated with the same order to be returned as a single row, appending columns to the result set for whatever number of products (and their details) the order has.

Here is the solution we came up with:

```
    select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippingmethodid, 
        p1.productcode as prod1code, 
        p1.productname as prod1desc,
        p1.quantity as prod1qty,
        p1.productprice as prod1price,
        p2.productcode as prod2code, 
        p2.productname as prod2desc,
        p2.quantity as prod2qty,
        p2.productprice as prod2price,
        p3.productcode as prod3code, 
        p3.productname as prod3desc,
        p3.quantity as prod3qty,
        p3.productprice as prod3price
    from Orders o
    outer apply (
        select *
        from (
            select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY od.orderid ORDER BY od.productname) as rn
            from OrderDetails od
            where o.orderid = od.orderid
        ) t
        where rn = 1
    ) as p1
    outer apply (
        select *
        from (
            select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY od.orderid ORDER BY od.productname) as rn
            from OrderDetails od
            where o.orderid = od.orderid
        ) t
        where rn = 2
    ) as p2
    outer apply (
        select *
        from (
            select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY od.orderid ORDER BY od.productname) as rn
            from OrderDetails od
            where o.orderid = od.orderid
        ) t
        where rn = 3
    ) as p3
    where o.orderstatus = 'Ready To Ship'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pivot table. See the static column's example. You can also make dynamic column pivot.

```
SELECT VendorID, [250] AS Emp1, [251] AS Emp2, [256] AS Emp3, [257] AS Emp4, [260] AS Emp5
FROM 
(SELECT PurchaseOrderID, EmployeeID, VendorID
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT (PurchaseOrderID)
FOR EmployeeID IN
( [250], [251], [256], [257], [260] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.VendorID;
```